# java.net.SocketException: Socket closed, JMeter

Tags: sockets, jmeter

I'm using JMeter with a load of 3-6 users. And I often get the exception below. Please, tell me what is the cause of this problem? Is this a trouble with JMeter or with server's application? thank you in advance.

Exception is next:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Basically you have filled the pipe.  The application you are taking POST'ing to has no more sockets available to respond. Try reducing the number of Threads (aka concurrent connections).

Answer (score 1):

Okay i had this problem and the solution i tried and worked was to update Java version. From 1.8 to 1.12.

As it is a Jar (a Java program compiled) if you try to run it with a previous version of java it might result in this error.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Search "Update Java" on your computer menu and select it, after, on the Java Control Panel, select the option "Update". Now, select "Update Now". Wait for the installation and don't forget to select "Ok" to the end.

When Java is update, the POST works on JMeter. This is the same solution of AndiFB's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?
If you upgraded recently to JMeter 2.10 or 2.11, you may have noticed increased errors of this type:

Socket closed
Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException (the target server failed to respond)

Explanation
The increase of this type of errors can be explained by two settings changes:

retry of failing request (idempotent ones only) has been disabled in JMeter 2.10
stale check in HTTP Client 3 and 4 implementations has been disabled in JMeter 2.11
Why these changes?
Previous retry default settings led to increased number of Requests in certain type of failures.

Previous stale check was a bit expensive, as it applied to every sample. That is why the default was changed to disable it.

Retry or stale check can hide issues on Server configuration:

Server failing to send the (optional) Keep-Alive header
Overwhelmed server refusing connection, retrying would increase load
Changing configuration:
If you think this server behavior is OK, then configuration can be changed in two places:

Enabling retry
For HttpClient 4, in user.properties set :

httpclient4.retrycount=1
This will make JMeter retry once. For HttpClient 3, in user.properties set:

httpclient3.retrycount=1
This will make JMeter retry once.

Enabling stale check
For HC4 Implementation:

In user.properties:

hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
In hc.parameters set:

http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
For HC3 Implementation:

In user.properties:

httpclient.parameters.file=httpclient.parameters
In httpclient.parameters set:

http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
New setting in JMeter 2.12
Upcoming version of JMeter adds a setting to add an idle connection timeout if the server does not send Keep-Alive headers.

This value is in milliseconds:

httpclient4.idletimeout=

Comment: Cite your sources: https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed, which is exactly the page mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: LoL, service unavailable on this wiki page. At least it's available in StackOverflow. Thankful.